# Cannot find output .class files using javac?

Tags: java, windows-7, javac

I type `javac helloworld.java` at cmd in win 7.

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\java_tut>javac HelloWorld.java

C:\Users\User\Downloads\java_tut>dir *.class

 Directory of C:\Users\User\Downloads\java_tut

03/28/2014  05:42 PM               429 YourClassName.class

C:\Users\User\Downloads\java_tut>
```

I searched the following directories for helloworld.class:
java, jre, jdk, java_tut, jre/bin, jdk/bin, and my entire harddrive.

I did need to manually add the /jdk/bin directory to my path.  I wonder if that matters?

Comment: I ran `javac HelloWorld.java`, and there is no output file (thusly, this question).

Comment: What is the package declaration of HelloWorld?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I'm writing my first program, man.  I don't know what that is.  Can you tell me how to look for the information you want?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the Java source file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `HelloWorld.java` compiled without any errors, then the file `HelloWorld.class` should definitely be in the `java_tut` directory.

**EDIT (based on your comments and edits):**

Check if your Java source file `HelloWorld.java` looks as follows:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hellow, World!");
    } 
}
```

The class must have the same name as the Java source file or you get following compiler error message:

```
[515]% javac HelloWorld.java 
HelloWorld.java:1: error: class YourClassName is public, should be declared in a file named YourClassName.java
public class YourClassName {
   ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 14):

Another possible reason is an empty *.java* source file.

This causes *javac* to silently produce nothing.

I experienced that effect with a Hello Word program and a Macintosh editor - which would save with *Cmd-S*, but does not save with *Ctrl-S*. I learned this after 20 years of Java programming.

Comment: Cannot imagine I got this for 10 minutes. Mine was saving to another location and keep trying to build the original file. Thanks any way. Mine was only 2 years though.

Answer (score 2):

Although I asked about the package declaration, I can tell you the correct approach:

Let's assume you have a Java class with that source:

```
package my.test;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World.");
    }
}
```

Assuming your project root directory is

> C:\Projects\java_tut

you must put the source file `HelloWorld.java` into the directory

> C:\Projects\java_tut\my\test

Afterwards you compile and start this little program while being in the `java_tut` directory with the following commands:

```
C:\Projects\java_tut> javac my/test/HelloWorld.java

C:\Projects\java_tut> dir my\test
[...]
28.03.2014  09:35    <DIR>          .
28.03.2014  09:35    <DIR>          ..
28.03.2014  09:35               434 HelloWorld.class
28.03.2014  09:34               134 HelloWorld.java
[...]

C:\Projects\java_tut> java my.test.HelloWorld
Hello World.
```

Explanation: If working with packages (and you always should use packages for your classes) you must not "sit" in that package, but always run the commands from outside the package (folder).

Comment: If this really was the problem, then `javac` should have failed, too?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also assume, that he got a compile error. What I wanted to show is the correct approach, a beginner should follow. With this procedure he should get a working program (and the expected output), regardless what problems he had before.

Answer (score 1):

`YourClassName.class` is the correct file in this case.  The class name isn't generated based on the .java file's name.  It's generated based on the class name inside the .java file.  In my .java file, I named the class `YourClassName` and not `HelloWorld`.

Comment: In this case you should have seen following compiler error message: "[515]% javac HelloWorld.java 
HelloWorld.java:1: error: class YourClassName is public, should be declared in a file named YourClassName.java"

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be. You have not saved your program. Before running javac command always save the program(if u did any changes then only). Then running javac command will produce .class file.